# Export subset of a collection base on a Date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework, mongoexport, isodate

I am trying to export data from mongoDB

```
mongoexport -d MY_DB_NAME -u DB_USER -p _REDACTED_ -c person \
-q "{ '$and':[ { 'hasActiveAck':{ '$ne':false }}, { 'creationDate':{'$gte': new Date(1506816000),  '$lte': new Date(1509404400)} }]}" \
--fields '_id,email' --type=csv --out people_oct.json
```

The problem is that this extracts 0 rows

If I call this query

```
db.getCollection('person') 
.find({  
$and:[  
  {  
     hasActiveAck:{  
        $ne:false
     }
  },
  {  
    creationDate:{ 
        $gte:new Date(1506816000) ,
        $lte:new Date(1509408000)
        }
  }
 ]
 }).count();
```

the result is `0` rows

But if I run the query with ISODate instead of Date like this:

```
db.getCollection('person') 
.find({  
$and:[  
  {  
     hasActiveAck:{  
        $ne:false
     }
  },
  {  
    creationDate:{ 
        $gte:ISODate("2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z") ,
        $lte:ISODate("2017-10-31T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
  }
  ]
  }).count();
```

The result is 58k+ rows

What am I doing wrong?

Some details:

`mongoexport --version`

```
mongoexport version: r3.2.11
git version: 45418a84270bd822db0d6d0c37a0264efb0e86d2
Go version: go1.7
 os: linux
 arch: amd64
 compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

`mongo --version`

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.14
```

`mongod --version`

```
db version v3.0.14
```

Comment: What is your goal?? export the data? or use the `$gte:new Date(...` ?

Comment: I'm trying to export the data

Comment: Did you check @JiříPospíšil solution? Is not working for you??

Comment: I did, but still no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor takes the number of milliseconds, not seconds.

```
new Date(1506816000).toISOString()
"1970-01-18T10:33:36.000Z"

new Date(1506816000000).toISOString()
"2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

> Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since January 1,
>   1970, 00:00:00 UTC, with leap seconds ignored (Unix Epoch; but
>   consider that most Unix timestamp functions count in seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Try spliting the problem into 2 phases.

The **first phase** will be to produce a collection with the desire documents:

```
db.person.aggregate([
    { $match : 
        {    $and:[ 
             { hasActiveAck:{ $ne:false } }, 
             { creationDate:{ 
                              $gte:ISODate("2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z") 
                             ,$lte:ISODate("2017-10-31T00:00:00.000Z")
                            }
             }]
        } 
    },
    {
        $out: "people_oct"
    }
])
```

Here you have to [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) doc.

The **second phase** will be to export this new collection:

```
mongoexport --db MY_DB_NAME --collection people_oct --type=csv --out people_oct.json
```